# SPO: Display column only on Edit Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, edit-form

I have a column called "Comments", i have hide this column to appear in New form.

But i want to make this column appear on **edit form** so i can see the related comments of the approvers and the "Comments" column should be **read only**.

Is it possible to only display it on Edit form and make it read only?

The type of the list is: **Classic Experience**.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using classic experience then you can hide this field from new form using javascript/jquery.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, do you have the JavaScript code to achieve this and make the column read only in the edit form ?

Comment: Check my answers given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254599/check-if-people-picker-has-any-value-on-document-ready-of-editform-aspx-in-jsom/254611#254611) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257922/column-permission-to-edit-the-data-for-a-specific-sharepoint-group/257923#257923).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check them out and reply back asap.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have a question, the type of my site is "Communication Site" and i have already enabled to allow scripts once i created the problem is i can't find Media and content to add a new script in the editor any idea why ?https://i.imgur.com/L3yvvxQ.png

Comment: I have tried to use the script you mentioned in one of those post which is about if the user is not in a specific group i can hide the fields and that's actually what i want to achieve, but after adding the script into an editor and checking my console i get this error: SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: '$' is not defined @GaneshSanap

Comment: You need to add a reference to JQuery file in order to use `$`.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap in your code you have already give reference to jQuery CDN, so why the issue still remain ?

Comment: Check if jquery is added to your page or not from browser console-->Source tab. Also check if you are adding jquery reference twice on the same page?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have 3 different scripts that are working perfectly using jQuery in same page, but i only get error in the latest script i've added in my console i get the following:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1506547

Comment: @GaneshSanap You can check out the code here: https://pastebin.com/pQ7RfNf3

Comment: If you have already added jQuery reference on the same page then remove the jQuery reference from the code I have given. You only need to add jQuery reference once in page.

Comment: Also you can download the SPService file from the URL mentioned in code, upload it to you SharePoint site maybe in Site Assets/Style Library and then refer it in your code. This files are not loading because we are referencing it from CDN.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Great so i have uploaded the files into my Site Assets library and now they load perfectly but i get an issue in the code which is: SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'SPGetCurrentUser' of undefined or null reference any idea why ?

Comment: Check if SPServices file is loaded properly or not. Else you can use [REST API](https://myclassbook.org/check-if-user-is-present-in-sharepoint-group/) or [JSOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654587/how-to-check-if-user-belongs-to-a-sharepoint-ad-group-or-not-using-rest-javascri) to check if the current user is member of particular SharePoint Group.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap i have check back my console in Mozilla browser that said:jquery-1.10.1.min.js request failed with status 404 it seems that the problem from this file, i've also tried the REST API to get the current user signed in but i didn't get any data in the console here is the code:[link](https://pastebin.com/1HwpCi2e)

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy [react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to your tenant so you could use it in communication site(modern and classic view, it's helpful for customizing modern site page also).

Demo:

OOB List definition.

[image]

Add the webpart into new form or display form.

[image]

Add script to hide the column.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('nobr:contains("AnotherField")').closest('tr').hide();
        })
    </script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for this helpful information i will check this out and reply back asap.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i know:

1. Site setting
2. Advanced Setting
3. Allow content type
4. then click on your "item" content type
5. Click on the column "Comments"
6. you will find three options, choose the "hidden" option (but it will just hide the column in the new & edit form, not to the view form)

Comment: Hi, i did the same steps but i didn't achieve my needs to show the column on edit form and make it as read only.

Comment: You can do it with PowerApps, but it needs a licence if you are going to share this form with guest users